# ReactJS - array in this.state is updated correctly on delete but result isn't rendered until later state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen variations of this question posted but none match my problem. I am displaying an array of text fields and want to be able to delete one of them. When the delete button next to any text field is clicked, the last item in the array disappears. However, I've checked this.state and the correct item was deleted, just the wrong one was taken from the rendered array. When I click a button that hides the text fields and then un-hide, the array is fixed and shows the correct item deleted. Why is this happening? The state is updated with what I want removed, but it seems like it renders something other than the state. I've tried using `this.forceUpload();` in the `setState` callback but that does not fix it.

I've included some relevant snippets from the code and can include more if needed.

```
export class Questions extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      choices: []
      ...
    };
  }

  deleteChoice = (index) => {
    let tempChoices = Object.assign([], this.state.choices);
    tempChoices.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({choices: tempChoices});
  };

  renderChoices = () => {
    return Array.from(this.state.choices).map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <TextField defaultValue={item.text} style={textFieldStyle} hintText="Enter possible response..."
                       onChange={(event) => { this.handleChoice(event, index); }}/>
            <i className="fa fa-times" onClick={() => { this.deleteChoice(index); }}/>
          </li>
        );
    });
  };

  render() {
    let choices = (
      <div>
        <div className="choices">Choices</div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderChoices()}
          <li>
            <RaisedButton label="Add another" style={textFieldStyle} secondary
                        onClick={() => { this.addChoice(); }}/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
    return (
      {choices}
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help, this is wicked frustrating.

Comment: i would do `tempChoices=this.state.choices.slice()` or filter() it. not sure that matters, probably doesn't...

Comment: Your title says "result isn't rendered until later state change" but your description sounds like a completely different problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a key other than the array index in your `renderChoices` function. You can read more about why this is the case in React's docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any
>   child with key will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed
>   (instead of reused).

Consider using `item.text` as the key or some other identifier specific to that item.

Comment: This is what I thought, but a quick test doesn't reproduce it: why does [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGpNPK?editors=0010) work?

Comment: Had a look at your example. Officially, it shouldn't work. But strangely it does. Maybe something with the way codepen works? The weird behavior you get in your code if 100% sure caused by using index as key, as described in the answer.

Comment: You can find a further explanation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/2x51we/can_someone_pls_explain_this_voodoo_magic_re_key/). If you use index as key, sometimes it works (as in your CodePen), when react notices that - despite unchanged index-key - the content of the element is different. Sometimes it doesn't work. Then react (wrongly) concludes from an unchanged index key, that the contents also did not change.

Comment: Thank you for the links and explanation, solved the problem.